# Why is 000-default.conf a symlink?

Tags: server, ssh, apache2, symbolic-link, text-editor

Why is 000-default.conf a symlink?
lrwxrwxrwx 1 cole cole   35 Mar  3 10:36 000-default.conf -> ../sites-available/000-default.conf

I am trying to use notepad via WinSCP to edit and save my changes to 000-default.conf but I get an error when I save my charges. How can I accomplish this?  I am handicap and have to do cut/paste then save and cannot use ssh to nano, etc.

Comment: Can you give us more information about the actual problem that you are dealing with?  If you're getting errors, it would be helpful for you to post the entire error in the body of your question.  So that we can parse the error more easily, please use three backticks (`) on the line before and three backticks on the line after any blocks of code or terminal input/output

Answer (score 0):

Apache allows for multiple “sites” to be defined with multiple configuration files. These are all stored in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` and can be enabled/disabled at any time. When you enable a site with `a2ensite`, a symlink is created between `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` and the source file. When you disable a site with `a2dissite` the link is removed and the source configuration file remains. You can see the same pattern with modules, as `a2enmod` creates a symbolic link in `mods-enabled` and `a2dismod` removes the link.

One note: be sure to reload or restart Apache after modifying your configuration files, otherwise any changes you make will not be reflected.

```
sudo service apache2 reload
```

Or

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```